# List Git commits between a and b, considering only first parents of b AND only first parents of a

Tags: git

With Git you can list all ancestors of `b`, excluding all ancestors of `a`:

```
git log a..b
```

You can also list all *first-parent* ancestors of `b`, excluding all ancestors of `a`:

```
git log --first-parent a..b
```

But I want to list all *first-parent* ancestors of `b`, excluding all *first-parent* ancestors of `a`. I haven't found any way to get the first-parent requirement to also apply to the negative part(s) of a revision range.

Is there a way to do this? If there's no way to do this using only Git commands, is there a plausible way to achieve this with a Bash script?

---

Some more detail. For this commit graph (parents shown in left-to-right order):

```
    b --> 9
          |\
          | \
          |  \
a --> 6   7   8
      |\  |   |
      | \ |   |
      |  \|   |
      3   4   5
       \  |  /
        \ | /
         \|/
          2
          |
          |
          1
```

`git log a..b` would list 9, 8, 7 and 5. `git log --first-parent a..b` would list 9 and 7. I'm looking for a way to list 9, 7 and 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build the two lists, and use grep to exclude one from another :

```
git rev-list --first-parent a > lista.txt
git rev-list --first-parent b > listb.txt

# use grep, use '-f' to read patterns from 'lista.txt',
# use '-v' to say "exclude these patterns"
cat listb.txt | grep -v -f lista.txt
```

You can avoid creating the files on disk ; in `bash` and `zsh` you can use a so called *process substitution* (syntax is : `<(command)`) :

```
git rev-list --first-parent b | grep -v -f <(git rev-list --first-parent a)
```

One extra flag you can use with `grep` is `-F, --fixed-strings`) : since in this case all patterns are flat strings (not regexps), you can indicate that to `grep`, it speeds things up

```
git rev-list --first-parent b | grep -v -F -f <(git rev-list --first-parent a)
```

Comment: This does work, but it dumps the entire history of both branches (might be tens of thousands of commits) which I was hoping to avoid. I ended up doing something very similar but iteratively grabbing commits from both branches until I saw the same hash on both sides.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use a shell trick to avoid dumping files to disk. This solution still makes `grep` build one of the lists completely in memory. It should still be very acceptable : from my experience `grep` can handle quite a massive workload.