# Is there a way to run `git cherry-pick` and specify the series of commits specific to a given branch?

Tags: git

For example:

```
feature        C---D---E---G---H---L---M
              /         \       \      ^--- tip of feature
master   A---B-----------F---I---J---K
                                     ^--- tip of master
```

The commits I want to cherry-pick are: `C D E G H L M`

The key requirement: **I don't want to specify any commit IDs manually** --- I want a reliable way to specify them in terms of "commits I made to `feature` since it diverged from `master`".  I don't want what's been put into `master` since `feature` diverged from it so I don't want `F I J K`.

The reason: I'd like to be able to cherry-pick those commits into a third branch, but I cannot just run `git merge feature` as it would also include additional ancestors such as `A` and `B`.  (I do not want to get into the reasons why there's stuff in `master` I don't want in the third branch.)

Does this make sense?

Comment: There is no generally clean way of doing this, because some of the commits in your range (`H` and `E`) are _merge_ commits, and have two parents.  You would need to specify which parent you want to follow.  Why do you want to cherry pick this way?

Comment: For this particular case, if you know `C` or `B` already, `git rev-list --first-parent feature ^B` lists out the right IDs. If you don't know `C` (which gets you `B`) or `B`, use LeGEC's method. @TimBiegeleisen: `H` and `E` are not merges; the merges are `F` and `J`, on `master`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get list of commits you want to pick by listing the first parents of `feature`, and remove the first parents of `master` ;
you can use the script provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944407/86072) :

```
git rev-list --first-parent master > listm.txt
git rev-list --first-parent feature > listb.txt

# use grep, use '-f' to read patterns from 'listm.txt',
# use '-v' to say "exclude these patterns"
cat listf.txt | grep -v -f listm.txt
```

In bash like shell, you can use `<(...)` to turn it into a one liner :

```
git rev-list --first-parent feature | grep -v -f <(git rev-list --first-parent master)
```

You can then feed that list to cherry-pick :

```
list=$(git rev-list ...)
git cherry-pick $list
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You can do it easily by rebasing the specific part of the graph that interest you to a new branch onto the *feature2* branch. The only tricky part is to identify the 1st commit to re-play (see bellow).

---

To make the reading easier, let's call your feature branch 'feature1'
let's say the branch you want your cherry-picked to go into is called 'feature2'

for now let's create a working branch from the feature1 branch (will will use this in few seconds). let's call it 'feature2-with-feature1-commits'

1. `git checkout feature1`
2. `git checkout -b feature2-with-feature1-commits`

now we can find the hash the feature1 was created from (the original master commit) by finding the previous commit of the 1st shared commit between *feature1* and *master* :
*git show $(git rev-list f1..master | tail -1)~1 --pretty=%h*
but we don't need to save it as we can now use rebase --onto command

so let's execute the third step that will contain the previous command to give to git the original commit to replay the commit from:

3. `` git rebase --onto feature2 `git show $(git rev-list feature1..master | tail -1)~1 --pretty=%h` feature2-with-feature1-commits ``

You have now all the commits we wanted from feature1 cherry-picked into the new branch (going out from feature2 latest commit) without master commits and you can now integrate them into the feature2 branch by merging them (`git checkout feature2; git merge --no-ff -;`) or by fast forwarding the feature2 branch (`git checkout feature2; git merge --ff-only -;`)